# Multiple echoes of an include error with set_error_handler

Tags: php, error-handling

Why is an include error echoed four times?

Does the system attempts 4 times to "open stream"?

I did :

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if ($errno == E_NOTICE ) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_NOTICE<br/>";
    }
    if ($errno == E_USER_NOTICE) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_USER_NOTICE<br/>";
    }
    if ($errno == E_DEPRECATED) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_DEPRECATED<br/>";
    }
    if ($errno == E_USER_DEPRECATED) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_USER_DEPRECATED<br/>";
    }
    if ($errno == E_STRICT) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_STRICT<br/>";
    }
    if ($errno == E_WARNING) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_WARNING<br/>";
    }
    if ($errno == E_USER_WARNING) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_USER_WARNING<br/>";
    }
    if ($errno == E_ERROR) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_ERROR<br/>";
    }
    if ($errno == E_USER_ERROR) {
        echo "<br/>".$errno."== E_USER_ERROR<br/>";
    }
}
set_error_handler("errorHandler");
```

Result :

```
2== E_WARNING

2== E_WARNING

2== E_WARNING

2== E_WARNING
```

Comment: To increase the chance of getting an answer, you should add a tag corresponding to the language you are using (php?).

Comment: Print out `$errstr` in the message.  I get 2 per failed include, one saying no such file or directory (because of trying to open the file) and the other saying the include failed.

Comment: Why don't you just do echo `$errno` and `$errstr` instead of those `if` statements?

Comment: @ William Isted  Errors are :3 times===> include(afile.php) [0function.include0]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../public_html/index.php on line 653 AND 1 once ===>include() [0function.include0]: Failed opening 'afile.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/.../public_html/index.php on line 653

Comment: I guess it's just the way it reports them, contribution to failure and ultimately the failure. Just a guess

Comment: @sachleen I did that before, then I wanted to simplificate the most. Error Messages are in answer to William Isted

Comment: @drew010 I get 4 per failed include, THREE saying no such file or directory and ONE saying the include failed.

Comment: Are each of the no such file or directory errors different paths that are all part of your `include_path`?

Comment: No Drew, it's the same path each time. It seems as if the test was read 3 times before issuing final comment "failed opening "afile.php"for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')ect...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing additional information pertaining to your error its hard to say.

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing. The
>   include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this
>   is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.

Docmumentation for [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

> PHP considers each entry in the include path separately when looking for files to include. It will check the first path, and if it
>   doesn't find it, check the next path, until it either locates the
>   included file or returns with a warning or an error. You may modify or
>   set your include path at runtime using set_include_path().

Per the PHP [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) on the include process.

On a side note, I've made a few modifications to your provided custom `errorHandler()` function.

```
<?php
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $response;

    switch ($errno){
        case E_NOTICE:
            $reponse = 'E_NOTICE';
            break;

        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            $reponse = 'E_USER_NOTICE';
            break;

        case E_DEPRECATED:
            $reponse = 'E_DEPRECATED';
            break;

        case E_USER_DEPRECATED:
            $reponse = 'E_USER_DEPRECATED';
            break;

        case E_STRICT:
            $reponse = 'E_STRICT';
            break;

        case E_WARNING:
            $reponse = 'E_WARNING';
            break;

        case E_USER_WARNING:
            $reponse = 'E_USER_WARNING';
            break;

        case E_ERROR:
            $reponse = 'E_ERROR';
            break;

        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $reponse = 'E_USER_ERROR';
            break;
    }
    echo "<br />Errno: [$errno]; Type: [$reponse]<br />";
    echo "<br />Error on line [$errline] in file [$errfile]<br />";
    echo "<br />Error: ". $errstr . "<br />";
}

set_error_handler("errorHandler"); 

?>
```

Comment: Hi RobB, after a short night, I was considering doing what you suggested. I tried your code....... but I get exactly the same behaviour : 3 TIMES ==>"Errno: [2]; Type: [E_WARNING]
Error on line [703] in file [/home/.../public_html/index.php]
Error: include(afile.php) [0function.include0]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory"   AND ONCE===>"Errno: [2]; Type: [E_WARNING] Error on line [703] in file [/home/.../public_html/index.php]
Error: include() [0function.include0]: Failed opening 'afile.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')". Driving me mad ... !